# How IoT Hub cryptographically validates the certificate chain?

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

How IoT Hub cryptographically validates the certificate chain for internal consistency and then issues a proof-of-possession challenge to the device ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following article that explains with an example on [How X.509 Certificates are used in Azure IoT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-x509ca-concept#example-scenario)

Here is the section of the [RFC article](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-3.1) where it explains about proof of possession
[image]